# Laravel 5 (Eloquent) JOIN entre duas consultas, é possível?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

A seguinte SQL, executa duas consultas e "soma" as duras respostas "lateralmente":

```
 select * from (select id,name from client  where id = 20) as a

 join  (select id,age from client  where id = 20) as b

 ON a.id = b.id
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer isso usando o eloquent, sem usar SQL puro (DB::Raw()). 
 As duas consultas isoladas ficariam assim:

```
 $query1 = DB::table('client')->select('id','nome')->where('id','=',20);
 $query2 = DB::table('client')->select('id','age')->where('id','=',20);
```

Agora, como fazer:

```
 $query1->join($query2)...:
```

Antes que me digam o óbvio "é possível ter a mesma resposta em uma única consulta", isso é apenas um exemplo, no contexto real, 
acredito que não seja possível trazer todas as informações de uma só vez.

Comment: Bem, dei a resposta, mas ainda acho que você quer é uma pouco diferente. WhereIn  no seu caso resolveria?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16848987/a-join-with-additional-condition-using-query-builder-or-eloquent

Comment: Condições na junção não resolve no meu caso, por que eu não consigo passar um objeto query como primeiro parâmetro no JOIN... Estou quase convencido de que o que eu quero fazer é impossível, agora estou entre, juntar os resultados via PHP. Ou escrever todo o código dentro de um DB::Raw(). A segunda opção é ruim, pois queria que meu sistema fosse completamente portavel, com relação a base de dados, mas se eu meter sintaxe de um SGBD especifico, isso vai por agua abaixo :(

Comment: Será que o método `$query->toSql()` não pode te ajudar?

Comment: Este método existe, aparentemente não? se eu conseguir obter a query que o eloquent gerou, e fazer o JOIN no braço, seria uma solução bem melhor. Mas, em outras ocasiões eu precisava acessar a SQL gerada (debug), e o único meio que encontrei foi utilizado "queryLog", que obtem a consulta, mas apenas após ela ser executada.

Comment: Isto não seria um UNION ou UNION ALL? **Mais informações aqui:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#unions